# error while plotting multiple lines using ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I would like to plot four lines and the data is randomly generated below:

```
trE <- runif(12, 0.5, 0.8)
teE <- runif(12, 0.8, 1)
trES <- runif(12, 0, 0.3)
teES <- runif(12, 0.3, 0.5)
plotData <- data.frame(k=1:12, trE=trE, teE=teE, trES=trES, teES=teES)
```

I have plotted it using the below code:

```
ggplot(plotData, aes(k)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = trE, colour = "Tr E")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = teE, colour = "Te E")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = trES, colour = "Tr ES"), linetype="dashed") + 
  geom_line(aes(y = teES, colour = "Te ES"), linetype="dashed") +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0.5), linetype="dotted",colour='red') +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("black", "orange","black", "orange"), 
                      labels=c("Tr E", "Te E", "Tr ES", "Te ES")) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=1:12) +
  theme_bw()
```

But the output is not as expected:

[image]

The line colors are messed up and they should be in the order: "orange","black", "orange", "black" in the plot.

```
ggplot(plotData, aes(k)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = trE, colour = "black")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = teE, colour = "orange")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = trES, colour = "black"), linetype="dashed") + 
  geom_line(aes(y = teES, colour = "orange"), linetype="dashed") +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0.5), linetype="dotted",colour='red') +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("black", "orange","black", "orange"), 
                      labels=c("Tr E", "Te E", "Tr ES", "Te ES")) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=1:12) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

However, in this plot, the line colors are as expected but the labels are not as expected.

Do you have any thoughts for this weird behavior? or point me to the missing details.

**update:**

```
plotDataLong <- plotData %>% tidyr::gather(Error, value, 2:5)

ggplot(plotDataLong, aes(k, value, col=Error)) + geom_line() + 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0.5), linetype="dotted",colour='red') +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("black", "orange","black", "orange"), 
                      labels=c("Tr E", "Te E", "Tr ES", "Te ES")) +
  scale_linetype(labels=c("solid","solid","dashed","dashed"))
```

[image]

Though the code is greatly simplified, the linetypes are not as expected.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Much better to tidy your data (`tidyr::gather`) before using ggplot. Greatly simplifies the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set.seed(1)
trE <- runif(12, 0.5, 0.8)
teE <- runif(12, 0.8, 1)
trES <- runif(12, 0, 0.3)
teES <- runif(12, 0.3, 0.5)
plotData <- data.frame(k=1:12, trE=trE, teE=teE, trES=trES, teES=teES)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(plotData, aes(k)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = trE, colour = "Tr E"),lwd=1) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = teE, colour = "Te E"),lwd=1) +
  geom_line(aes(y = trES, colour = "Tr ES"), linetype="dashed",lwd=1) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = teES, colour = "Te ES"), linetype="dashed",lwd=1) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0.5), linetype="dotted",colour='red') +
  scale_colour_manual(
     values=c("Te E"="orange","Tr E"="black", "Te ES"="orange", "Tr ES"="black"),
     breaks=c("Te E", "Tr E", "Te ES", "Tr ES")) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=1:12) +
  theme_bw() +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(keywidth = 2, 
    override.aes = list(linetype = c("solid", "solid", "dashed", "dashed"))))
```

[image]

Comment: Please check, the colors and line types are not as expected(or given in the commands).

Comment: +1 for the mistake identified. Still, the labels are not in sync. There are no dashed labels for `Te ES`, `Tr ES`. How to make it show these expected changes?

Comment: yes.. exactly. The dashed lines are not present in the labels(sorry, I meant `legend`).

Comment: Thanks for the expected output.  [Alternatively](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46580250/4836511), it can be achieved easily using `tidyr::gather`.

Answer (score 1):

As per @Richard's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46545850/error-while-plotting-multiple-lines-using-ggplot/46580250#comment80046391_46545850), I have tried using `tidyr::gather` and the expected solutions below.

```
plotDataLong <- plotData %>% tidyr::gather(Error, value, 2:5)

ggplot(plotDataLong, aes(k, value, col=Error,linetype=Error)) + geom_line() +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0.5), linetype="dotted",colour='red') +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("black", "black", "orange", "orange"),
                      name="Errors",
                      breaks=c('teE', 'teES',  'trE', 'trES'),
                      labels=c("Te E", "Te ES", "Tr E", "Tr ES")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(labels=c("Te E", "Te ES", "Tr E", "Tr ES"),
                 name="Errors",
                 breaks=c('teE', 'teES',  'trE', 'trES'),
                 values=c("solid","dashed","solid","dashed"))
```

[image]